# MySQL - How to sort alphanumeric data on numbers

Tags: mysql, sorting

I try to sort one of my column which contains alphanumeric data in MySQL. Data start with chars and ends with digits.

Here is my sample dataset :

```
insert into test_sort (port) values ('GI 1/0/1');
insert into test_sort (port) values ('GI 1/0/4');
insert into test_sort (port) values ('GI 1/0/10');
insert into test_sort (port) values ('GI 1/0/6');
insert into test_sort (port) values ('GI 1/0/3');
insert into test_sort (port) values ('GI 1/0/12');
insert into test_sort (port) values ('TE 1/1/3');
insert into test_sort (port) values ('GI 1/1/1');
insert into test_sort (port) values ('GI 2/0/11');
insert into test_sort (port) values ('GI 2/0/1');
insert into test_sort (port) values ('GI 2/0/3');
insert into test_sort (port) values ('GI 1/1/2');
insert into test_sort (port) values ('TE 1/1/4');
```

I try to get this output :

```
GI 1/0/1
GI 1/0/3
GI 1/0/4
GI 1/0/6
GI 1/0/10
GI 1/0/12
GI 1/1/1
GI 1/1/2
TE 1/1/3
TE 1/1/4
GI 2/0/1
GI 2/0/3
GI 2/0/11
```

I tried to order by length, with substrings, binary, *1 with no success.

Many thanks for any help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM test_sort
ORDER BY 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(PORT,'/',1),' ',-1)+0,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(PORT,'/',2),'/',-1)+0,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(PORT,'/',3),'/',-1)+0;
```

**test query**

```
SELECT t.*,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(PORT,'/',1),' ',-1)+0 as D1,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(PORT,'/',2),'/',-1)+0 as D2,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(PORT,'/',3),'/',-1)+0 as D§
FROM test_sort t
ORDER BY 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(PORT,'/',1),' ',-1)+0,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(PORT,'/',2),'/',-1)+0,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(PORT,'/',3),'/',-1)+0;
```

Comment: Thanks for this proposal, unfortunately it did not provide the expected result. I got `GI 1/0/1`, `GI 1/0/4`, `GI 1/0/10`, `GI 1/0/6`, ...

Comment: Ther was a error in my answer. in the third line with SUBSTRING_INDEX you must change the 2 to 3. Also i have add a test query that outputs the found numbers. Sorry, please check again

Comment: Sorry too, I should have noticed. It returns the result I expected. Many thanks. I was stuck trying with `substring` but `substring_index` is way better because I don't have to worry about the length of each chunk. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

No built-in sort functionality or collation is going to skip into the 4th character in your string and sort based on that.  If you really need this kind of sort, you should probably split this string into two fields and then perform a two-dimensional ordering.

i.e. a table like:

```
port_alpha   port_numeric
----------   ------------
GI           2/0/1
TE           1/1/3
...          ...
```

with query like:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', port_alpha, port_numeric) AS port
FROM test_sort
ORDER BY port_numeric ASC, port_alpha ASC
```

Without splitting your field you could do something like:

```
SELECT port FROM test_sort
ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(port, ' ', -1) ASC, port ASC
```

This is not ideal in that this would disallow use of an index on port field for performing the sort, and make this a poorly performing query.

Comment: With the query without splitting the field I get `GI 1/0/1` then `GI 1/0/10` so it is not like expected.

Comment: @Lotus This is really the same as the original problem in that there is no natural sorting methodology in MySQL (end even if there were, it would likely not be able to appropriately sort numeric values with non-numeric characters injected between them).  This mean your will need to continue to either break apart your single column into more columns or break apart the string in a single columns into it's constituent parts using `SUBSTRING_INDEX` like I have done.

Comment: Splitting is most likely the way to go. However, I thought MySQL would be able to sort based on identical parts in each row (`GI 1/0/` for instance). I thought of using binary conversion (`order by bin(port)`) but it did not work either.

Comment: I tried to split into two columns as you suggested (port_alpha, port_numeric) and tried various queries, including your proposal.
I still get `1/0/1`, `1/0/10`, ... The root of the problem is this in my opinion

Comment: @LoTus Yes. I hadn't noticed the desire to do "natural" sort on the "numeric" part in my original post.  Per last comment you would need to split into 4 columns if you want to do column split, or use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to chunk up the `ORDER BY` clause for each numeric value (like being suggested in other answer).

Comment: Yes, @bernd solution suits best. Thanks for your proposals.